# Do different API keys associated on the same usage plan share the same quota limit too?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless, api-key

Do different API keys associated on the same usage plan share the same quota limit too?

Scenario:

- Usage Plan 1 has quota of 1 million requests per month.
- API Key #1 is associated to Usage Plan 1
- API Key #2 is also associated to Usage Plan 1

When API Key #1 consumes 1 million requests in a month, does this mean requests with API Key #2 will all be throttled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usage plan is calculated per API key. From the documentation: "Throttling and quota limits apply to requests for individual API keys that are aggregated across all API stages within a usage plan".

You can read more about usage plans in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html)

Comment: That sentence in the docs is confusing, so I tested it out and can confirm that the throttling limits are per API key

Comment: I think that sentence is very confusing. To be clear: if api keys K1 and K2 are both connected to usage plan UP1 and UP1 is connected to API stages AS1 and AS2, will users of K1 get 1M requests per month on API1 + 1M requests per month on API2 - or 1M shared for requests to API1 and API 2, e.g. 300k+700k?